# Unknown parent package

Tags: python

Looked at all similar discussions, but I can't have clue.
I have the following structure

```
ava folder
    main.py
utils folder
    __init__.py
    collect_env.py
    distribution_env.py
    gradcam_utils.py
    logger.py  
    misc.py  
    module_hooks.py 
    precise_bn.py  
    setup_env.py
```

`__init__.py` has

```
from .collect_env import collect_env
from .distribution_env import build_ddp, build_dp, default_device
from .gradcam_utils import GradCAM
from .logger import get_root_logger
from .misc import get_random_string, get_shm_dir, get_thread_id
from .module_hooks import register_module_hooks
from .precise_bn import PreciseBNHook
from .setup_env import setup_multi_processes

__all__ = [
    'get_root_logger', 'collect_env', 'get_random_string', 'get_thread_id',
    'get_shm_dir', 'GradCAM', 'PreciseBNHook', 'register_module_hooks',
    'setup_multi_processes', 'build_ddp', 'build_dp', 'default_device'
]
```

In main.py, tried to import

```
from ..utils import (collect_env, get_root_logger, register_module_hooks, setup_multi_processes)
```

Then the error is

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: `parent package` is the key. To be a package, you need to put the `__init__.py` in main too. And when you are running, you should run your code with a working directory outside the ava folder.

Comment: Added `__init__.py` inside ava. Then run from outside of ava like `python ava/main.py`. Still have same error as `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. Is `__init__.py` in ava an empty file?

Comment: try running it like `python -m ava.main`. And yes, if you have the `__init__.py` already, you don't need to import `from ..utils`, you can just use `from utils ....`

Comment: `from utils ...` has another error as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`

Comment: I took out main.py from ava and put same level as utils. It worked